# About the English word "bromance"

Tags: vocabulaire

I would like to know if French can offer a similar [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau#Standard_English) formation as a translation for this word, which would preserve its spirit from the original language.

So, I am not interested in any paraphrases such as *amour fraternel*, which are too easy to think of and even come up with as reasonable French alternatives to this term.

What I am interested in is whether French has the linguistic means to form a similar formation that would preserve the flavor of the original word.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but in my experience French is likely to borrow the word even if it has the linguistic resources. To give a shot at coining one, though, perhaps romamitié ? :) For what people actually say we'll have to wait for more of an expert than myself to come by.

Comment: @LukeSawczak _Romamitié_ seems to be a very good alternative to _bromance_, indeed.

Comment: French has been using the French word [*bromance*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromance) for [quite some time](http://www.slate.fr/story/136820/fin-bromance) now. Is your question specifically about *bromance, for which now there's little probability of a new word coming up, or on the ability of French in creating [mots-valises](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot-valise). Of course French can create a lot of those ! [A few examples](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/mots-val.html).

Comment: @Laure About both, but more about the latter.

Comment: A question on mots-valises in general is far too broad, we could only copy the wikipedia article and refer you to sites that list them...

Comment: What an awful word. The wikipedia article says: particularly high level of emotional intimacy. I think the word has been used by PR people more than anything else. Men can be close friends but that does not imply "emotional intimacy". Not every close friendship involves "emotional intimacy.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I have strong doubts about  "Romamitié", too close to romanité and liable to oral confusion. *Framitié* (fraternité /amitié) would have been a better choice in French but I doubt we reverse now...

Comment: @Lambie I don't judge words in moral or aesthetic terms. Words are just words, and if a word exists, so does one's right to make any inquires into it as one sees fit.

Comment: @Laure *Framitié*, I like that and may have to use it (even if "une bromance" is firmly established). As for *bromance* in English, it's used often enough by my generation, but mostly ironically. I have yet to hear anyone say "bromance" with a straight face. :p It's like packing the [old Seinfeld bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OH1yEnENG0) into one word. In any case, it seems like a quick answer could be made out of these observations (in short, that French does have the resources to make such portmanteaus but often borrows anyway and has done so in this case)?

Comment: Pour info le terme recommandé par le dictionnaire terminologique (Québec) est "amitié virile". Ce n'est pas un mot-valise mais c'est une bonne traduction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

French has been using the word [*bromance*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromance) for quite some time now, just borrowed it from English.
An article about the word *[La bromance: un léger parfum d'homophobie](http://www.slate.fr/story/136820/fin-bromance)* by a French journalist shows it is mainly associate to Anglos Saxon culture. So doe this other one: [*La bromance, qu’est-ce que c’est ?*](https://dragonaplumes.fr/2014/01/20/la-bromance-quest-ce-que-cest/) by a French writer.

Although it is used by journalists:

> On nage en pleine bromance. Ce vendredi matin, Emmanuel Macron et Justin Trudeau se sont rencontrés pour la toute première fois dans un décor de rêve en Sicile. (20 minutes, [26/05/2017](http://www.20minutes.fr/high-tech/2075383-20170526-video-macron-trudeau-rencontrent-cadre-bucolique-toile-roue-libre))

it hasn't reached a lot of French dictionaries, I only found one occurrence in the [Cordial online dictionary](http://dictionnaire.cordial-enligne.fr/definition/bromance):

> Définition de bromance
> nom féminin singulier
> Amitié forte entre deux hommes, sans composante sexuelle.

Bilingual dictionaries do not have it yet except [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/bromance) that translates it as *amitié virile*.

Not that French does not have portmanteau words. The Wikipedia entry for [*mot-valise*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot-valise) tells us that:

> Le mot-valise, appelé techniquement amalgame lexical, est connu depuis le XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle (Rabelais a par exemple créé le mot « sorbonnagre » en amalgamant « sorbonne » et « onagre »). De nombreux mots-valise sont entrés dans le langage courant, mais il est courant d'en créer de nouveaux par jeu (amalgames fantaisistes).

We can find lots of articles on the internet about *mots-valises* including [that one](http://monsu.desiderio.free.fr/curiosites/mots-val.html), on the *Cabinet des curiosités*, often quoted on French Language.
Teachers like to have pupils work on them whether in primary school<sup>1</sup>, or secondary school<sup>2</sup>

If I had to create a *mot-valise* for "bromance", *framitié* would come spontaneously to my mind.

<sup>1. For example: http://blog-du-petitvictor.over-blog.com/article-4640643.html</sup>
<sup>2. For example: http://col21-albertcamus.ac-dijon.fr/spip.php?article324</sup>

---

#### Edit for update

Running an ngram in 2001 shows an increase in the use of the word "bromance" in French.
[image]

Comment: Plutôt framance, non ? (Parce que personellement, je traduirais framitié par brotherhood ou briendship)