# Bromance : est-il courant ?

Tags: usage

Peut-on utiliser couramment le mot bromance ? Sera-t-il reconnu ?

> Une bromance est une amitié forte entre deux ou plusieurs hommes, avec un niveau émotionnel élevé et des démonstrations d'intimité fortes, sans composante sexuelle. (wikipédia)

Comment: Avant de poser ta question as-tu pensé à actualiser la réponse qui est faite à cette question [*About the English word “bromance”*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/26387/358)?

Comment: J'ai actualisé la réponse vieille de 4 ans. Juste demander si le mot est reconnu ne peut amener que des réponses subjectives : ça dépend reconnu par qui ? dans quel contexte ? etc.